# Which resistor do I need to replace to power a Gumstix Pre-Go board with 3.3 V?

Tags: power-supply, gumstix

I purchased a Gumstix Pre-Go PPP with SMA connector. On the [product page](https://store.gumstix.com/prego-ppp-sma.html), it states:

> Logic levels are at 3.3V, and the board is powered by the 5V supply; however, by removing and replacing a jumper resistor, the board can be powered by a 3.3V source.

Which specific resistor is it that needs to be removed, and what are the specifications of the resistor that it needs to be replaced with, in order to power this GPS module with a 3.3 V source?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you need to resolder this resistor to the spot next to it in order to use the 3.3V PS.

[image: photo]

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIFyo.png))

Answer (score 0):

According to Gumstix,

1. DNP `R4` on the top-side, saving the resistor for the next step.
2. Populate the resistor salvages in the previous step to `R5` (on the top-side as well next to R4).
3. The board can now be powered directly from 3.3V provided on pin 4 of `U3` (labelled as 3.3V on the bottom of the board).

For reference this is the part that we are moving: [0603 0-ohm resistor](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-dale/CRCW06030000Z0EA/541-0.0GTR-ND/1174156).